# How to customize Mac Google Chrome keyboard shortcuts - Switch to the last(rightmost) tab?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, tabs

The default shortcuts for `Switch to the last(rightmost) tab` is <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>, I want change it to another.

I know how to customize keyboard shortcuts for menu items, but it does not display in menu.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows users, the Chrome extension [AutoControl Shortcut Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/autocontrol-shortcut-mana/lkaihdpfpifdlgoapbfocpmekbokmcfd?hl=en) lets you remap native shortcuts or create new ones.

Switching to the rightmost tab is one of many actions available for you to choose.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am using Mac.